# Does "\d" in regex mean a digit?

Tags: python, regex, encoding, gedit

I found that in `123`, `\d` matches `1` and `3` but not `2`. I was wondering if `\d` matches a digit satisfying what kind of requirement? I am talking about Python style regex.

Regular expression plugin in Gedit is using Python style regex. I created a text file with its content being

```
123
```

Only `1` and `3` are matched by the regex `\d`; `2` is not.

Generally for a sequence of digit numbers without other characters in between, only the odd order digits are matches, and the even order digits are not. For example in `12345`, the matches are `1`, `3` and `5`.

Comment: `\d` will match `1`, `2` and `3`. If it doesn't there must be something else in your expression. Can you show your full expression?

Comment: `\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]`, so it ought to match `2`.  Please post a complete test case (a script that can be run, which demonstrates your problem) and maybe we can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @delnan: "I found that in 123, \d matches 1 and 3 but not 2" sounds pretty concrete to me.

Comment: @Amber: Damn me, I missed the not!

Comment: \d matches only 1 in 123. Try \d+ to match 123.

Comment: What happens if you put a space in between the 1 and the 2, and add a 4 immediately after the 3?  (I suspect this is either a bug or a deliberate design decision in gedit's search-by-regexp mechanism.)

Comment: @Zack: for a sequence of digit numbers without other characters in between, only the odd order digits are matches, and the even order digits are not. For example in `12345`, the matches are `1` `3` and `5`.

Comment: Okay, I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't *know*, but I think what's going on is gedit refuses to start a new match immediately after the end of the previous match -- it skips one character, whatever it is, before trying to match again.  Please try matching `11111` and `22222`.

Answer (score 597):

`[0-9]` **is not always equivalent** to `\d`.  In python3, `[0-9]` matches only `0123456789` characters, while `\d` matches `[0-9]` and other digit characters, for example Eastern Arabic numerals `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`.

Comment: Trying this in the REPL: `import re, re.match(r'\d', '٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩')` shows no match

Comment: For Persian and Arabic , in java and javascript engines, use \p{Nd}

Comment: That's not correct. Not all engines implement it like that. Onigurum and Onigmo (used e.g. in Ruby) have \d == [0-9], if you want other scripts' digits, you have to use \p{digit}

Comment: +1, but mmmm... the OP's tag is `Python` and `\d` matches any Unicode digits only in Python3. In Python 2.7 it's still the old ASCII `[0-9]`—it could be worth clarifying that in the answer. :)

Comment: php here : `preg_match()` returns false for `١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`, so `\d` == `[0-9]`

Comment: Is there any equivalent to \d if say we only want to match 1 of English, Arabic and others too.

Comment: @FarazAhmad, probably not, you have to specify all characters separately

Comment: If you want `\d` to only match `[0-9]`, you can use the ASCII flag. E.g.: `re.search('\d', 'string_to_search', flags=re.ASCII)`. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.ASCII

Comment: u used Persian digits, just use English ones 0123456789

Answer (score 22):

`\d` matches any single digit in most regex grammar styles, including python.
[Regex Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Answer (score 16):

In Python-style regex, `\d` matches any individual digit. If you're seeing something that doesn't seem to do that, please provide the *full* regex you're using, as opposed to just describing that one particular symbol.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'\d', '3')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02155B80>
>>> re.match(r'\d', '2')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02155BB8>
>>> re.match(r'\d', '1')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02155B80>
```

Comment: Thanks! My regex parser is regular expression plugin in gedit. The whole content is `123`.

Answer (score 11):

`\\d{3}` matches any sequence of three digits in Java.

Comment: @amal-murali , How to use this expression in order to match any sequence of digits in java.

Comment: @HasanKhatib: `\\d+`

Answer (score 8):

This is just a guess, but I think your editor actually matches every single digit — `1` `2` `3` — but only odd matches are highlighted, to distinguish it from the case when the whole `123` string is matched.

Most regex consoles highlight contiguous matches with different colors, but due to the plugin settings, terminal limitations or for some other reason, only every other group might be highlighted in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Info regarding  .NET / C#:

> Decimal digit character: \d
>   \d matches any decimal digit. It is equivalent to the \p{Nd} regular expression pattern, which includes the standard decimal digits 0-9 as well as the decimal digits of a number of other character sets.
>
> If ECMAScript-compliant behavior is specified, \d is equivalent to [0-9]. For information on ECMAScript regular expressions, see the "ECMAScript Matching Behavior" section in Regular Expression Options.

Info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#decimal-digit-character-d

Comment: When using '\d' with Regex source generators, it uses `char.IsDigit()`, which generalizes to `CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber`. This matches anything in the Nd category: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Nd