# Regexp: Why isn't my regexp filtering properly?

Tags: regex

I have never got my head around using regular expressions, so I have a bit of an issue understanding why my below listed regex. doesn't only allow the below listed characters:

- A-Z & a-z (upper & lower)
- ÅÄÖ & åäö
- 0-9 & _ (underscore)

Here's the regex:

```
/^[\s\da-0-9-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ_]$/i
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `\d` and `0-9` are redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this `a-0-9-z` is in reverse order. Use this: `^[\s\da-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ_]$` or this: `(?i)^[\s\da-zåäö_]$` with ignore case option set to enabled.

Also you can use special character `\w`, which means: `letters, digits, and underscores`

In you regex you're using `\d` and `0-9`. `\d` includes `0-9`, see [**Explanation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479423/does-d-in-regex-mean-a-digit/6479605#6479605)

Comment: @Industrial, What do you mean?

Comment: Running the regexp you provided (`^[\s\da-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ_]$`) with a string containing `&` or `&` doesn't filter `&` or `&` out as I need

Comment: @Industrial, this `^[\s\da-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ_]$` will match only string which have length of `1` character. If your string is `@` or `&`, this regex shouldn't match. But if your string is `whitespace`, `digit`, `a-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ` or `_`, it will match.

Comment: @Industrial, If input string is `a` it will match, if input is `aa` it won't match. If you need to match string, which contains only these chars, you need to set `+` (one or more repetitions), i.e.: `^[\s\da-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ_]+$`

Answer (score 0):

Is the expression here a verbatim copy? Because in

```
/^[\s\da-0-9-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ_]$/i
```

you have

```
a-0-9-zA-Z
```

where you probably mean

```
0-9a-zA-Z
```

Answer (score 0):

the mistake is **a-0-9-z** which should be **a-z0-9**

furthermore, you can lose the 0-9 cause you used \d, and you can use \w for any "word" character.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match a signle character string and case insensitive in the following : any space character, any digit (0-9), any letter (a-ZA-Z), and one of åäöÅÄÖ_ .

Answer (score 0):

Dunno about the latin, but you don't need `0-9` if you use `\d`, also, you don't need `a-zA-Z` if you use the `/i` flag, that makes everything case insensitive so you could leave just `a-z`.