# Using regex to extract multiple numbers from strings

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string with two or more numbers. Here are a few examples:

```
"(1920x1080)"
" 1920 by 1080"
"16 : 9"
```

How can I extract **separate** numbers like "1920" and "1080" from it, assuming they will just be separated by one or more non-numeric character(s)?

Comment: Please decide which language you need the answer in. The regex objects in .NET are not the same as the Java ones.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The basic regular expression would be:

```
[0-9]+
```

You will need to use the library to go over all matches and get their values.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(myString, "[0-9]+");

foreach(var march in matches)
{
   // match.Value will contain one of the matches
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the string by following

```
MatchCollection v = Regex.Matches(input, "[0-9]+");
foreach (Match s in v)
            {
                // output is s.Value
            }
```

Comment: `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` is not needed. Roman numerals don't have upper/lower cases.

Comment: Normally i practice with RegexOptions.IgnoreCase. Sorry for mistake

Comment: Not a mistake as such. Just not needed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
(\d+)\D+(\d+)
```

After that, customize this regex to match the flavour of the language you'll be using.

Comment: `\d` will contain _all_ digits, not only roman numerals, depending on regex library and platform.

Comment: .net / C#'s (and PCRE's) regex `\d` matches [0-9]. Period.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It will match on ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩ -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6479605/1583

Comment: If the character is defined as a Unicode digit, it will be matched in .NET by `\d`.

Comment: Could you explain the advantage of this over Regex.Matches(s, "[0-9]+");?

Comment: @Oded Your first comment confused me until I realised that you didn't mean `I`, `II`, ... `VII` etc. Aren't 0-9 Arabic?

Comment: @Rawling - Yes, they are. Badly put by myself. Meant the digits normally used in the west, versus other scripts.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
string[] input = {"(1920x1080)"," 1920 by 1080","16 : 9"};
foreach (var item in input)
{
    var numbers = Regex.Split(item, @"\D+").Where(s => s != String.Empty).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", numbers[0], numbers[1]);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1920,1080
1920,1080
16,9
```