# Creating local copy of passed props in child component in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, deep-copy, vue-cli

In vue.js what is the right way to edit prop without changing parent data?
What I mean by that is whenever we pass any property from parent to child in vue.js then if we make any change to that property in child component then the change is also reflected in parent's component.

Is there any way in vue.js to make a local copy of passed property in a child?

I googled this but everywhere it is written that we can achieve this by doing this.

```
 props:["user"],
  data(){
    return {
      localUser: Object.assign({}, this.user)
    }
  }
```

here the user is passed an object and I am creating a copy of it in local user but it doesn't work at all, the local user is undefined.

Have you encountered a scenario like this where you have to make changes to a parent property in child component without affecting the state of parent component i.e- making your own copy in child and then edit it?

Any insights on this will be helpful.

I have also read somewhere that in In vue@2.3.3，when we want to pass a prop from Father to Child component, we need to manually create a local data to save the prop, that makes lots of useless works.

we can maually create the local data like this :

```
props: ['initialCounter'],
data: function () {
    return { counter: this.initialCounter }
}
```

but this is not working in my case as well.
I am using vue cli 3.0.1 for the developemnt purpose.

Here is my code for the same.

In my application I have a list view.

[image]

When user clicks on the **See Focused View** button user is redirected to below mentioned view i.e is actaully a bootstrap - modal view.

[image]

Here user can edit the value of Name, but as I am passing name here as a property from aprent component so editing it here causes it to update on parent component as well i.e in the list view as well.

Comment: @tony19 you can follow this fiddle for easy of access - https://codesandbox.io/s/j4n13vxw6w

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In your [fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/j4n13vxw6w?file=/src/components/Test.vue:465-512), the child component is using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create a copy of `data`, which is an array of objects. However, this only creates a [*shallow copy*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184710/6277151), so the array elements would still refer to the original instances, leading to the behavior you're seeing.

A few solutions to deep copy the array:

- Use [`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), which works reasonably well for [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) object properties (`String`, `Number`, `BigInt`, `Boolean`, `undefined`, and `null`):

  ```js
  data() {
    return {
      local_data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data))
    }
  }
  ```

  ([demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/vxqlzyo3))
- Map the objects into new ones, which works well if the depth is only 1 (nested arrays/objects will still be shallow copied):

  ```js
  data() {
    return {
      local_data: this.data.map(x => ({...x}))
    }
  }
  ```

  ([demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/kmj3w46lz3))
- Use a utility library, such as `lodash`'s [`cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep):

  ```js
  data() {
    return {
      local_data: _.cloneDeep(this.data)
    }
  }
  ```

  ([demo 3](https://codesandbox.io/s/7kzxrl4po1))

Comment: This was a great explanation that I needed after a few hours of getting no where.

Comment: This helps so much, I love the multiple examples. Does demo 1 have any issues with date objects in the arrays?

Comment: @CaineNielsen `JSON.stringify` will convert `Date` objects to `String` (via `Date#toString`), so they would need to be [revived in `JSON.parse`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488745/javascript-json-date-deserialization).

Comment: It still feels hacky to do this cloning stuff. Is there really no better solution than cloning objects?

Comment: @Walnussbär Objects are passed by reference in JavaScript, so cloning is the only way to separate the original reference from the new object (as of 2023...maybe the language could change in the future).

Comment: I know, but every time I have to do this it feels not good/ like a big overhead. But yeah, the language needs to change in order to circumvent this.