# Vue editing v-data that has been passed to a component as a prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt `2.15.3`.

In my app, users can set up Questions that their customers can answer, and the questions can be a variety of types, one of them being a Multiple Choice question. These types of questions have a title, as well as multiple answer options that people can choose from.

On my Questions page, I list all of the User's questions, and I want to allow them to edit any question, but I'm having some trouble figuring out how to do that exactly, at least when it comes to editing multiple choice questions. As it stands currently, I have a `EditQuestion` component to which I pass a `question` prop from my `QuestionCard` component, the prop just being the details of the question which is stored in Vuex.

My current (simplified for SO) version of the `EditQuestion` component:

```html
<template>
  <input v-model="questionTitle" type="text">
  <div v-if="question.type === 'multiple_choice'">
    <input v-for="option in questionOptions" v-model="option.content" type="text">
  </div>
  <button @click.prevent="updateQuestion"></button>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      question: {}
    },
    data() {
      return {
        questionTitle: this.question.title,
        questionOptions: this.question.options
      }
    },
    methods: {
      updateQuestion() {
        // Call the API with the new question details
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

If I were only editing question titles, this works great. However, my issue comes from the options. If I try to update one, Vuex warns me about mutating the store state outside of a mutation, and it warns me all the same even if I clone `question.options`, for example by doing `questionOptions: Object.assign({}, this.question.options)` or `questionOptions: {...this.question.options}.` The part that confuses me is why Vuex doesn't complain when I modify the `questionTitle` data object, and only when editing the questionOptions?

For reference if it's relevant, `question.title` is just a simple string, while `question.options` is an object that looks something like this:

```json
{
  "0": {
    "id": 0,
    "content": "Option 1"
  },
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "content": "Option 2"
  }
}
```

What is the best way for me to allow people to edit the Multiple Choice question options?

Comment: Did you tried to use Lodash's `cloneDeep` method? Because it is maybe complaining because you are trying to modify a reference of the object. Rather clone all the object and update the copy rather than the reference. There is not Vuex shown here, but usually this kind of thing is nice when done in a Vuex action directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#primitive_values) (`String`, `Number`, `BigInt`, `Boolean`, `undefined`, and `null`) are copied *by value*, while [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#objects) (including `Array`, `Map`, `WeakMap`, `Set`, `WeakSet`) are copied *by reference*.

`this.question.title` is a `String`, so it gets copied by value into the new variable. On the other hand, `this.question.options` is an object (it looks like an `Array`), so it's copied by reference into `questionOptions`, and thus `questionOptions` and `this.question.options` refer to the same object in Vuex.

Your idea of cloning the incoming `this.question.options` is on the right track to a solution, but [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#warning_for_deep_clone) and the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) only create shallow copies that still refer to the same original object, which explains the Vuex state-mutation warnings when your component tried to modify the shallow copy.

There are several [ways to deep-copy an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52467000/6277151), one of which is provided in [the other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68853354/6277151):

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      questionTitle: this.question.title,
      questionOptions: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.question.options))
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-clone-object-prop?file=components%2FEditQuestion.vue)

Answer (score 1):

Try making a local copy of the `question` object and do all the updates on that local copy only, something like this:

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      question: {}
    },
    data() {
      return {
        localCopyOfQuestion: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.question)),
        questionTitle: this.localCopyOfQuestion.title,
        questionOptions: this.localCopyOfquestion.options
      }
    },
    methods: {
      updateQuestion() {
        // Call the API with the new question details
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```