# Timestamp verification in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I need to check if the value of a particualr property is actually an ISO 8601 format.

`2006-11-05T13:15:30Z`

So, if someone enters some string as a property, I need to check whether it is per the format of ISO 8601.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

What have I tried?
`strftime` - could not find if there is a simple way of checking if the input string is on the same lines as the ISO format.

Comment: can you show us your use of `strftime`?  That seems to be a logical choice..

Comment: You may use `std::regex` ([tag:c++11]) or `boost::regex` to accomplish this.

Comment: have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756159/regex-and-iso8601-formated-datetime