# Reading 'ipconfig' with Python-Pexpect

Tags: python

I'm running freeSSHd on win XP as an SSH server and it's returning CMD shell for authenticated users, and I want to get the result of sending 'ipconfig' command automatically when I run the python script, I got the connection working but I have an issue with reading the result for each field and putting it in separate variable, the result for my code is '4' instead of '10' > first digit in IP address, I don't know where did number 4 come from. Any idea?

Output of Win XP ipconfig

C:\Documents and Settings\hussam\Desktop>ipconfig

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.10
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.15

C:\Documents and Settings\hussam\Desktop>
```

My Code

```
import pexpect
import re

def sendcommand(conn,command):
    conn.sendline(command)
    conn.expect('\d')
    print conn.after

def c(ip,username,password):
    global conn
    ft = 'ssh '+username+'@'+ip
    print 'we are trying to connect to ' + ft
    new = 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting'
    conn = pexpect.spawn(ft)
    result = conn.expect([ pexpect.TIMEOUT , new ,'[P|p]assword:' ])
    if result == 0:
        print 'connection error'
        return
    if result == 1:
        conn.sendline('yes')
        result = conn.expect([ pexpect.TIMEOUT , '[P|p]assword:'])
    if result == 0:
        print 'connection error'
        return
    conn.sendline(password)
    conn.expect('>')
    sendcommand(conn,command)



def main ():
    global command
    username = 'hkhrais'
    ip = '10.0.2.10'
    password = 'hkhrais'
    command = ' ipconfig'
    c(ip,username,password)


 main ()
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse the output of ipconfig? Where is your code?

Comment: Yes , for example i want to put the result of IP address in variable x , and subnet mask in y and so on , rest of the code is working fine nd it's for initiating the SSH connection

Comment: Where is the code you are using to parse the data?

Comment: Why not use the WinAPI to access the information instead of parsing output that's meant for humans?

Comment: I need to automate this , here's the full code

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: In `sendcommand()`, instead of `conn.expect('\d')` you might need `conn.expect('[0-9]+')`. See [Does “\d” in regex mean a digit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479423/does-d-in-regex-mean-a-digit).

Comment: @ martineau, same result

Answer (score 0):

It is way simpler to use [`WMI`](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html#show-the-ip-and-mac-addresses-for-ip-enabled-network-interfaces):

```
import wmi

def return_ip_addresses(user,passwd,machine):

    i = wmi.WMI(machine, user=user, password=passwd)

    addresses = []

    for interface in i.Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration(IPEnabled=1):
      for ip_address in interface.IPAddress:
         addresses.append(ip_address)

    return addresses

if __name__ == '__main__':      
   print return_ip_addresses('user','secret','10.1.1.1')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but i need to know what's wrong with my script.