# How to map all numbers in a string to a list in Python?

Tags: python, string

Say I have a string like

```
"There are LJFK$(#@$34)(,0,ksdjf apples in the (4,5)"
```

I want to be able to dynamically extract the numbers into a list: `[34, 0, 4, 5]`.
Is there an easy way to do this in Python?

In other words,
Is there some way to extract contiguous numeric clusters separated by any delimiter?

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-of-a-string

Comment: If the string were `"12.34"`, would you want `[12, 34]` or `[12.34]`?  IOW, is it only contiguous-digit integers you want?

Comment: In this case it would be [12, 34], integers. The current answer works as desired (I just can't accept it yet)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> s = "There are LJFK$(#@$34)(,0,ksdjf apples in the (4,5)"
>>> import re
>>> list(map(int, re.findall(r'[0-9]+', s)))
[34, 0, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Using a list comprehension is usually preferable to using `map`. Especially since you're just casting the result to a list anyway.

Comment: @Cairnarvon It usually is, except if you can simply call an existing function (because then you don't have to figure out the name of a temporary variable). The list creation is just for the nice output. If you were to iterate over the result, you could obviously skip it.

Comment: You could have use `\d+` for the regex too.

Comment: @Schoolboy Yes, but then one would have to use something significantly more complicated than `int` to support inputs like `٣٤`.

Comment: @phihag Why is that?? how will those inputs get through the filter??

Comment: @Schoolboy `\d` matches arbitrary digits (and [is **not** equivalent to `[0-9]`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6479605/35070)), and those characters [are](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/663/index.htm) [digits](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/664/index.htm). Therefore, [`'٣٤'` matches `r'\d'`](http://ideone.com/3k1I43).

Comment: @phihag Ok, now I get it. Thanks learned something new.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this without regular expressions, although it requires some more work:

```
>>> s = "There are LJFK$(#@$34)(,0,ksdjf apples in the (4,5)"
>>> #replace nondigit characters with a space
... s = "".join(x if x.isdigit() else " " for x in s)
>>> print s
                   34   0                      4 5
>>> #get the separate digit strings
... digitStrings = s.split()
>>> print digitStrings
['34', '0', '4', '5']
>>> #convert strings to numbers
... numbers = map(int, digitStrings)
>>> print numbers
[34, 0, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I think I like this even better than the `itertools.groupby` solution I was going to propose.

Comment: This is a great solution too