# Does regular expression \d match minus sign and/or decimal point?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm look at some old PERL/CGI code to debug an issue and noticed a lot of uses of:

```
\d - Match non-digit character
\D - Match digit character
```

Most online docs mention that \d is the same as [0-9], which is what I've always thought of it as. But, I've also noticed Stackoverflow Questions that mention character set difference.

[Does "\d" in regex mean a digit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479423/does-d-in-regex-mean-a-digit)

**Does \d also match a minus sign and/or decimal point?**

I'm off to do some testing.

Comment: Use `[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?` to match minus plus sign and or decimal point ...

Comment: I was thinking of something more strict, such as /^[0-9]+$/ , which should match from start to end with one or more 0-9.

Comment: I though you wanted to match decimal (+-) numbers :p If you want to match only digits then `/^\d+$/` is fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know how Perl determine whether to use Unicode or ASCII or locale **by default** (no flag, no `use`). Regardless, by declaring `use re '/a';` (ASCII), or `use re '/u';` (Unicode), or `use re '/l';` (locale), you will clearly signify to the Perl interpreter (and human reader) which mode you want to use and avoid unexpected behaviour.

Due to the effect of modifiers, `\d` has at least 2 meanings:

- Under effect of `/a` flag (ASCII), `\d` will match digits from `0` to `9` (no more and no less).
- Under effect of `/u` flag (Unicode), `\d` will match any decimal digit in any language, and is equivalent to `\p{Digit}`<sup>[reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Digits)</sup>. This effectively makes `\d+` pretty useless and dangerous to use, since it allows a mix of digits in any languages.

  Quote from description of `/u` flag

  > And, `\d+` , may match strings of digits that are a mixture from different writing systems, creating a security issue. [`num() in Unicode::UCD`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Unicode/UCD.html#num%28%29) can be used to sort this out. Or the `/a` modifier can be used to force `\d` to match just the ASCII 0 through 9.

`\d` will not match any sign or punctuation, since those characters does not belong to `Nd` (Number, decimal digit) [General Category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aGeneral_Category_%28Unicode%29) of Unicode.

Comment: Do you consider \D (Match non-digit character) to be as "dangerous to use"?

Comment: @ikegami: Using flag will set the behaviour. But what is the default behaviour - where will Perl gets its setting from if we don't set anything?

Comment: @jjwdesign: If you are using it in a validation regex, then you would like to review it. `\D` will match Unicode character regardless of the flag you are using.

Answer (score 11):

> Does \d also match a minus sign and/or decimal point?

## NO

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. It merely does a digit check. However, Unicode makes things a bit more complex.

If you want to make sure something is a number -- a decimal number -- ake a look at the [Scalar::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html) module. One of the functions it has is `look_like_number`. This can be used to see if the string you're looking at could be a number or not, and works better than trying to use a regular expression.

This module has been part of standard Perl for a while, so you should have it on your system.