# String Replace not work

Tags: c#, json, string, parsing, replace

I have a string (an example of its value is `{"id":"123241077871_4423423423414"}`) and I only require the part with the numbers and the underscore. However, my way of doing it with the `String.Replace` method doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

This is what I've tried:

```
Settings.Default["lastid"].ToString().Replace('{"id":"'+"}',null);
```

Comment: Well that's invalid C# to start with, so you should be getting a compile-time error... It's not a valid string literal. I would suggest avoiding direct string manipulation here anyway - just parse it as JSON and use the parsed value.

Comment: And for future reference your questions should expand on the way in which something doesn't work. Wrong result? Compiler error? Runtime error? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be

```
Settings.Default["lastid"].ToString().Replace("{\"id\":\"", "").Replace("\"}","");
```

As Jon Skeet said, currently, it's not a valid string literal. In addition, Replace only searches for one string of text. You can't do both of them in one pass.

Comment: That's a fairly intense way of pointing out an extra semicolon. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a [real json parser](http://json.codeplex.com/) and doing it the right way

```
var id = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(s, new { id = "" }).id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this :

```
Settings.Default["lastid"].ToString().Replace("{\"id\":","");
Settings.Default["lastid"].ToString().Replace("\"}\"","");
```

Comment: Your code won't remove the opening and closing quotes around the 123241077871_4423423423414.

Answer (score 0):

Just in one pass with regex

```
string test = Settings.Default["lastid"].ToString();
string result = Regex.Replace(test, @"[^0-9_]", @"");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The regex pattern means:

- match any character NOT included (^) inside the brackets
- and replace it with an empty string.

As noted by @newStackExchangeInstance in the comments below, the pattern `[^0-9_]` could be changed in `[^\d_]` to keep excluded from the replacement also other `Unicode Numerical Characters`

Comment: Use `[^\d_]` instead. It's better, as it means if he gets some unicode numerical chars, they still count as numbers and are not replaced.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Sorry, I am not aware of this. Could you point me to an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479423/does-d-in-regex-mean-a-digit Look at the top answer. (Sidenote: I know it says python, but it applies to C# as well)

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance well, good to know, not of immediate usage for me, but thanks. I will fix my answer with your findings

Answer (score 0):

Try using Regex.

```
string json = @"{""id"":""123241077871_4423423423414""}" //or whatever your value is
Regex.Match(json, @"{""id"":""(\d+_\d+)""}".Groups[1] //will give you your result
```