# Regular Expression for mandatory and number only

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make regular expression that allow only numbers and must be mandatory. no blank field or white space allow using asp regular expression validater with C#. i tried this 
 ValidationExpression="^[/d]*+$". this is working for number only. blank field accepted by this expression.

Thanks

Comment: What @Mr47 is saying is `^\d+$` (the slash direction is also wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful that `\d` can match digits other than `0` to `9`, such as [Eastern Arabic numerals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6479605). I would suggest using:

```
"^[0-9]+$"
```

Comment: Thanks all Dears, I tried all of your solution but not working here is my code                                                                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" Text="*"
                     ValidationExpression="^[0-9]+$"
                        ValidationGroup="vg1" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtReading" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Only Numbers allowed"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Answer (score 2):

The RegexValidator isn't called when the field is empty, you must use the RequiredFieldValidator in combination : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Besides, the correct regex would be

```
^\d+$
```

\d is for any number

+ is for 1 to n occurences

Answer (score 0):

Take out the "*". The "+" is being applied to the results of the previous expression which is "0 or more digits" and is always found.

```
ValidationExpression="^[/d]+$"
```

Comment: Using '/' instead of '\' probably doesn't help either.

Comment: Good point! Was looking at the iteration and missed that.

Comment: i tried alll but no solution