# How to combine these regex requirements?

Tags: regex

I'm using an Asp.Net RegularExpressionValidator to validate phone numbers.

The check is quite basic - a number can be 10 or 11 characters in length, all numeric and starting 01 or 02.

Here's the regex:

```
^0[12]\d{8,9}$
```

However, I've recently started working with a 3rd party, who enforce stricter rules. In my opinon it's a bad idea - partly because they don't even publish these rules, and they are subject to change and therefore maintenance across all their partners. However...

I now need to incorporate their additions into my regex, but I'm not sure where to start.

They currently do this using 2 separate regexes in an OR, however I'd like to do this in 1 if possible.

The additional syntax should ensure that for 10 digit phone numbers also adhere to these additional rules - here's their 10 digit syntax.

```
"^01(204|208|254|276|297|298|363|364|384|386|404|420|460|461|480|488|524|527|562|566|606|629|635|647|659|695|726|744|750|768|827|837|884|900|905|935|946|949|963|995)[0-9]{5}$
```

Any ideas as to how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you checking if the input adheres to `regex1` **AND** `regex2` or `regex1` **OR** `regex2` ?

Comment: It can only be 10 or 11 digits

Comment: You didn't get my question. If it can only be 10 or 11 digits then `[0-9]{10,11}` would do the job. What I'm asking how are you checking both regexes ? Are you using in the if statement an `and` or an `or` ?

Comment: I think this question is entirely valid, however if anyone thinks it should be closed, please be brave enough to give a reason!

Comment: I'm using a single Asp.Net validator - regex.

Comment: Last attempt to understand each other. Please read this [pseudo code](http://pastebin.com/buYqen1B). Which one are you using currently ? Otherwise can you provide your ASP code ?

Comment: All I have to do in the Asp.net validator is set the value of the regular expression - currently ^0[12]\d{8,9}$. There is no AND/OR or anything else

Comment: You don't seem to understand my point... The answer you accepted doesn't make sense. If that's the right behaviour then you could just write `^0[12]\d{8,9}$`

Comment: Yes, that equates to what I have now, however as I've explained 1 of the 3rd parties I work with has imposed further restrictions. If a 10 digit phone number is entered - digits 1 to 5 are validated explicity from the list - if an 11 digit number is entered no further tests are done.

Comment: ok, that wasn't really clear from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge them with an OR in the regex itself:

`^(?:01(204|208|254|276|297|298|363|364|384|386|404|420|460|461|480|488|524|527|562|566|606|629|635|647|659|695|726|744|750|768|827|837|884|900|905|935|946|949|963|995)\d{5}|0[12]\d{9})$`

Edited 11 digit regex.

Answer (score 2):

> **Disclaimer:** This answer is based on the logic followed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698288) to demonstrate the "virtual" requirements (which we should drop anyways).

Let me explain what is going on:
`^0[12]\d{8,9}$` What's going on here ?

- `^` : match begin of line
- `0` : match `0`
- `[12]` : match `1` or `2`
- `\d{8,9}` : match a digit 8 or 9 times
- `$` : match end of line

`^01(204|20...3|995)[0-9]{5}$` What does this big regex do ?

- `^` : match begin of line
- `01` : match `01`.
- `(204|20...3|995)` : match certain 3 digit combination
- `[0-9]{5}` : match a digit 5 times
- `$` : match end of line

Well, what if we merged these two in an OR statement ?

```
^
   (?:
       01(204|20...3|995)[0-9]{5}
   )
   |
   (?:
        0[12]\d{8,9}
    )
$
```

I'll show you why it doesn't make sense.
How many digits does `0[12]\d{8,9}` match ? 10 or 11 right ?
Now how many digits does the other regex match ?

```
01(204|20...3|995)[0-9]{5}
^^ ^-----\/-----^ ^--\/--^
2    +    3      +    5     =   10
```

Now if we compare the 2 regexes. It's clear that `^0[12]\d{8,9}$` will match all the digits that are valid for the other regex. So why in the world would you combine these 2 ?

To make the problem simpler, say you have regex1: `abc`, regex2: `[a-z]+`. What you want is like `abc|[a-z]+`, but that doesn't make sense since `[a-z]+` will match `abc`, so we can get ride of `abc`.

On a side note, `\d` [does match more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6479605/) than you think in some languages. Your final regex should be `^0[12][0-9]{8,9}$`.

Comment: HamZa - you failed to notice that the final regex has been changed so that {8,9} has become just {9}. I do take on board what you are saying about \d and have replaced with [0-9] in the final regex.

Comment: I did see it but I was so focused on the OR part that I completely ignored it. I do fail :P