# Regex replace hexadecimal characters

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and unable to create a expression to resolve my problem.

I have a string like `/abc/def%20hi%28hello%29test`. I would like to replace the hexadecimal characters, that is, `%20`, `%28` and `%29` with `-`

I know all three of them have different meanings, but I am fine with replacing all with any single character, I mean `-` or even `.` or ' '(space).

So, I would like to get the output as `/abc/def-hi-hello-test`.

I thought to find `%` and replace three characters from `%[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]` with `-`, but doesn't work.

Can some please help me write a regex which just replaces those hexadecimal characters?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "doesn't work"? Using your example, what output does it give?

Comment: Your regex will match all your examples... and actually more than you want since hex only goes `a-f`.

Comment: We need to know [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) in a more specific way - are you writing this in a program?  or are you trying to use this in a text editor's search and replace dialogue?  Regular Expressions are not language independent - you should consider writing a [Short, Self Contained, Compilable Example](http://sscce.org) so we can better diagnose your problem.

Comment: Seems fine, you could potentially even change it to `%[A-Z0-9]{2}` or `%[A-Z\d]{2}` for easier reading (depending on Regex engine).

Comment: @Chris You would need to remember the case-insensitive flag for that.

Comment: Your regex looks fine (except for including `G-Z`, which you were unlikely to have noticed since you just said it "doesn't work", which is really not specific enough). Please construct an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) in the language / tool of your choice, which should include an easily reproduceable test case which doesn't work.

Comment: @Dukeling Fair point, I'd assumed he'd grabbed a URL encoded something and he'd always have upper case letters (I'm now not sure why I left the entire range of letters in place). Derp.

Comment: I'm under the impression the OP needs the global flag `g` (or equivalent).

Comment: You may need to complicate it quite a bit to be 100% correct - I would guess that `%%28` shouldn't become `%(`, because `%%` is an escaped `%`.

Answer (score 3):

Search for:

```
%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]
```

replace with:

```
-
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/qR6xW7

Comment: Making it shorter `(?i)%[a-f0-9]{2}` :)

Comment: I don't think regex is the true issue the OP is having as his example would actually match. I believe it is the replace he is having problems with... which we can't really help him with without knowing the language he is using.

Comment: @HamZa Or even shorter by replacing `0-9` with `\d`.

Comment: @HamZa, that is dependent on regex engine.

Comment: @Dukeling Well `\d` [also matches](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6479605) hindu, arabic or hebrew digits.

Comment: @smerny You got the idea, setting the `i` modifier :)

Comment: @HamZa That's news to me, though I'll probably continue to pretend they mean the same, at least in my pet projects, since I don't ever work with non-0-9 digits.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you *really* want to do is decode the URL encoding, and I will bet you that your host language has a facility for that built in.  In PHP, that's [url_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

After you've decoded the URL, then you can modify what it is you want to modify more easily.