# Python regex for dollar amounts including commas and decimals

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to python and I'm writing a bit of code that needs to take a block of text and  remove anything that's not a dollar amount.  For example, the number two thousand may be represented as 2000 2000.00 2,000 and 2k. I'm trying to accomplish this with a single regex replacement.

Right now I have:

```
f=re.sub([0-9]+?(,[0-9])*?[0-9]+?(.[0-9])*?[TtBbMmKk],"",f)
```

While I understand that this is completely incorrect and does not compile, I'm not proficient enough to know what to do about it.  Can anyone give me some guidance? Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can start by wrapping the regex within single quotes. And add an `r` in front: `f=re.sub(r'[0-9]+?(,[0-9])*?[0-9]+?(.[0-9])*?[TtBbMmKk]',"",f)` (I cannot answer why there's the need for the `r` though).

Comment: Maybe you could describe in more detail what you are trying to do?  What sort of text is the input?  Can you give us an example input and desired output string?

Comment: @Jerry the `r` denotes a raw string literal, in which backslashes are not escape characters - it avoids the 'double backslash' phenomenon present in other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
import re
blockOfText = 'two thousand may be represented as 2000 2000.00 2,000 and 2k'
' '.join([ ''.join(x[0]) for x in re.findall(r'(\$?\d+([,\.]\d+)?k?)', blockOfText) ])
```

That gets you a new text string that you could assign to `blockOfText` if you want, effectively removing anything that's not a dollar amount.

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression needs to be put into a Python string:

```
f=re.sub(r"[0-9]+?(,[0-9])*?[0-9]+?(.[0-9])*?[TtBbMmKk]","",f)
```

The `r` prefix on the string makes this a raw string literal.  This will cause all of the backslashes in the string to be interpreted literally, which means you do not need to escape the backslash when you want to use it in a regular expression (for example `r'\w'` to match a word character instead of `'\\w'`).

So now you should at least be able to run this code and test the regular expression, I am not sure if the behavior is exactly what you want.

Comment: You can really shorten this regex by replacing `[0-9]` with `\d`.

Comment: @iCodez If you want to be on the safe side, you would keep it as `[0-9]`. :)

Comment: @Jerry Why would that be safer?

Comment: @Jerry That's a `c#` question. What does it have to do with Python? (Besides, since when does faster mean safer?)

Comment: @Jerry That's not even the case in Python.

Comment: @JosephDunn The question was asked for C#, but it is valid for _all_ regular expressions, across any language. If the OP has characters such as persian digits, they will match as well.

Comment: @arshajii Are you sure? Then I guess [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6479423/1578604) is more relevant to you.

Comment: On Python 3.x `\d` will match foreign language digits by default.  On Python 2.x you would need to be operating on a unicode string with the `re.UNICODE` flag enabled.

Comment: @Jerry Sure, it's the case in Python 3 but not in Python 2. I guess I spoke too soon.

Comment: @arshajii Well, you don't know the Python version the OP is using, so you'd be taking a risk!