# How can I validate mobile number that start with 8801, 05, 06, 07, 09, 01 and length is total 13

Tags: php, regex

I'm new in php, I'm trying to validate a mobile number using Regular Expression. It's total length is 13 and must start with 88016 or 88017 or  88015 or 88018 or 88019 or 88011. So the number format is look like this:

```
88016XXXXXXXX OR 88015XXXXXXXX OR 88017XXXXXXXX OR 88019XXXXXXXX OR 88011XXXXXXXX
```

But I'm tired. Please see following code. I think there is a wrong in my expression..

```
if( !preg_match("/^([0-9]-)?[0-9]$/", $write_numer))            
     $err[] = "Please enter a valid phone number";
```

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
if (preg_match("/^8801(6|5|7|9|1)\d{8}$/", $value)) {
        echo "yes";
}
```

Comment: `\d` matches any digit including foreign digits [Does “\d” in regex mean a digit?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6479605/1700963)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$pattern = "/^(880)(16|15|17|19|11)(\d){8}$/";

if( !preg_match($patterm, $write_numer))            
     $err[] = "Please enter a valid phone number";
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
preg_match("/^8801[5-7|1|9][0-9]{8}$/", $write_numer)
```

Comment: it should not contain 88018.....