# Regular Expression For Parsing Data

Tags: c++, regex

I am writing an application that reads some data from a simple text file. The data files,
that I am interested in, have lines in the following form:

```
Mem(100) = 120
Mem(200) = 231
Mem(43) = 12
...
Mem(1293) = 12.54
```

So, as you can understand, the pattern of each line is something like

```
(\s)*(\t)*Mem([0-9]*) (\s,\t)*= (\s,\t)*[0-9]*(.)*[0-9]*
```

like I have any number of whitespaces before the character sequence "Mem", followed by
a left parenthesis. Then, there is a number and a right parenthesis. Afterwards, there is any number of white spaces until an '=' (equals) character is encountered. Then, any number of white spaces until I come across a (possibly) floating point number.

How can I express that in a C++ regex pattern? I am really new to the regular expression concept in C++ so I would need some help.

Thank you

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. If you want to know how to use regex in C++, there are plenty of examples out there. By the way, you should probably escape your brackets - `...Mem\([0-9]*\)...`.

Comment: @Dukeling that is why I asked here. I could neither find a similar example out there, nor I could figure out how the regular-expression pattern matching works.

Comment: Regular expressions are overkill for such a simple pattern. Read the line into a string, search for `(`, search for `)`, search for the next digit.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First of all, remember to `#include <regex>`.

C++ `std::regex_match` works like the regular expressions in other languages.

Let's start with a simple example:

```
std::string str = "Mem(100)=120";
std::regex regex("^Mem\\([0-9]+\\)=[0-9]+$");
std::cout << std::regex_match(str, regex) << std::endl;
```

In this case, our regex is `^Mem\([0-9]+\)=[0-9]+$`.
Let's take a look at what it does:

- The `^` at the beginning tells C++ this is where the line starts, so `AMem(1)=2` should not match.
- The `$` at the end tells C++ this is where the line ends, so `Mem(1)=2x` should not match.
- `\\(` is a literal `(` character. `(` has a very special meaning in regular expressions, so we escape it `\(`. However, the `\` character has a special meaning in C++ strings, so we use `\\(` to tell C++ to pass the `\(` to the regular expression engine.
- `[0-9]` matches a digit. `\\d`should also work, but [then again maybe not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479423/does-d-in-regex-mean-a-digit).
- `[0-9]+` means **at least one** digit. If `Mem()` is acceptable, then use `[0-9]*` instead.

As you can see, this is just like the regular expressions you'd find in other languages (such as Java or C# ).

Now, to consider whitespace, use `std::regex regex("^\\s*Mem\\([0-9]+\\)\\s*=\\s*[0-9]+\\s*$");`

Note that `\s` includes `\t`, so no need to specify both. If it didn't, you'd use `(\s|\t)` or `[\s\t]`, not `(\s,\t)`.

Finally, to include float numbers, we first need to think if `Mem(1) = 1.` (that is, a dot without a number after it) is acceptable.

If it isn't, then the `.23` in `1.23` is **optional**. In regexes, we use `?` to indicate that.

```
std::regex regex("^[\\s]*Mem\\([0-9]+\\)\\s*=\\s*[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?\\s*$");
```

Note that we use `\.` instead of just `.`. `.` has a special meaning in regular expressions - it matches any character - so we need to escape it.

If you have a compiler that supports raw strings (e.g. [Visual Studio 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), [GCC 4.5](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), [Clang 3.0](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)), you can simplify the regex string:

```
std::regex regex(R"(^[\s]*Mem\([0-9]+\)\s*=\s*[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\s*$)")
```

To extract information about the matched string, you can use `std::smatch` and **groups**.

Let's start with a small change:

```
std::string str = " Mem(100)=120";
std::regex regex("^[\\s]*Mem\\(([0-9]+)\\)\\s*=\\s*([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)\\s*$");
std::smatch m;

std::cout << std::regex_match(str, m, regex) << std::endl;
```

Note three things:

1. We added `smatch`. This class stores extra result info about the match.
2. We added additional parenthesis around `[0-9]*`. This defines a group. Groups tell the regex engine to keep track of whatever is within them.
3. Yet more parenthesis around the floating point number. This defines a second group.

Very importantly **the parenthesis that define groups are NOT escaped** since we don't want them to match actual parenthesis characters. We actually want the special regex meaning.

Now that we have the groups, we can use them:

```
for (auto result : m) {
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

This will first print the whole string, then the number in `Mem()`, then the final number.

In other words, `m[0]` gives us the whole match, `m[1]` gives us the first group, `m[2]` gives us the second group and `m[3]` would give us the third group if we had one.

Comment: You can also use raw string literals to get rid of the escape sequences. `R"regex(hello\world)regex"`

Comment: @DyP Yeah, since `regex` is C++11 anyway, raw string literals *should* be available. Unfortunately, some C++ implementations such as Visual Studio that support regexes do not support raw string literals.

Comment: @luiscubal Thank you very much for your answer. It really helped me a lot. My follow-up question would be how to grab the number inside the two parenthesis. Like if I have Mem(Num) how can I isolate the Num string?

Comment: @popanik Take a look at my new answer. Groups are what you need.

Comment: `std::regex regex(R"^[\s]*Mem\([0-9]+\)\s*=\s*[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\s*$")` does not compile for me (GCC 6.2.0), you need the syntax `R"(^[\s]...$)"`

Comment: @oLen Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Relevant link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/regular-expressions-cpp