# Can somebody please tell me how to do this Regex expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a string and I want to capture the number inside it and then add one to it!.

For example I have an email subject header saying "Re: Hello (1)"

I want to capture that 1 and then raise it by 2, then 3,then 4,etc. The difficulty I am having is taking into consideration the growing numbers, once it becomes say 10 or 100, that extra digit kills my current Regex expression.

```
      int replyno = int.Parse(Regex.Match(Subject, @"\([0-9]+\)").Value);
      replyno++;
      string Subject = Subject.Remove(Subject.Length - 3);
      TextBoxSubject.Text = Subject + "("+replyno+")";
```

Comment: Post your current regex expression.

Comment: String will always starts from `Re: Hello..`?

Answer (score 2):

`Re: Hello \([0-9]+\)`

This matches the string "Re: Hello (1)" with any number of digits as the number, so it also matches "Re: Hello (100)".

Note that I have specifically used `[0-9]` and not `\d` to match a digit, because they are different. `\d` will match numeric characters in other languages, too. See this question and answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6479605/1801

If you need to match other numeric characters, you can replace `[0-9]` with `\d`

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
\((\d+)\)
```

as a regular expression.
This captures a number inside `()`, regardless of the numbers size thanks to `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex expression to `\d+`. That'll help you support multi-digit numbers.