# Regex Grouping with Repeat Operators

Tags: regex, perl, language-agnostic

I am using groups to try to match on a certain pattern, and am not getting quite the results I expect.  The pattern of interest are as follows:

```
([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+)
```

For string `1.23`, I get `$1=1.23`, and `$2=.23` which makes sense to me.

But for string `1.2.3`, I get `$1=1.2.3` and `$2=.3`, where I would expect `$2=.2.3`, because its group is a decimal point and a digit, repeated.

Can someone please explain to me how this works? Thank you!

Comment: You're close. To get what you are after in `$2`, you need another set of parentheses. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"These pattern match variables are scalars and, as such, will only hold a single value. That value is whatever the capturing parentheses matched **last**."

http://blogs.perl.org/users/sirhc/2012/05/repeated-capturing-and-parsing.html

In you example, `$1` matches `1.2.3`. As the pattern repeats, `$2` would be set to `.2` until the final match of `.3`

Answer (score 4):

When you use capturing groups with a quantifier, only the *last* repetition of the captured pattern will be stored.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this regex will meet your needs:

```
\b(\d+)((?:\.\d+)+)\b
```

This regex separates the leading integer sequence from its repeating fractional components.

(As indicated by @ysth, please keep in mind that `\d` may [match more characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6479605/1497596) than you intend. If that is the case, use the character class `[0-9]` instead or use the `/a` [modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers).)

Here's a Perl program that demonstrates this regex on a sample data set. (Also see the [live demo](http://ideone.com/iwuerw).)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    # A - A sequence of digits
    # B - A period and a sequence of digits
    # C - Repeat 'B'.

    if (/\b(\d+)((?:\.\d+)+)\b/) {
#           ^^^     ^^^^^
#            A        B
#                   ^^^^^^^
#                      C

        print "[$1]  [$2]\n";
    }
}

__END__
1.23
123.456
1.2.3
1.22.333.444
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[1]  [.23]
[123]  [.456]
[3]  [.2.3]
[4]  [.22.333.444]
```

Comment: changing `[0-9]` to `\d` matches a whole lot more characters (unless you also use the /a flag)

Comment: @ysth - [Does “\d” in regex mean a digit?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6479605/1497596). Does that answer fully define what you mean by "a whole lot more characters"?

Comment: From the [PerlRE doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html): `/d`, `/u` , `/a` , and `/l` , available starting in **5.14**, are called the **character set modifiers**; they affect the character set semantics used for the regular expression. ... The `/a` modifier, on the other hand, may be useful. Its purpose is to allow code that is to work mostly on **ASCII** data to not have to concern itself with Unicode.