# What is a better regular expression/ regex than my pattern for testing a house number?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to allow the following pattern: either any number or two numbers with a hyphen between them, so basically a house number.

This works so far but seems a little weird to me: `/^(\d)+$|^([\d]+-[\d]+)$/g`

This correctly valids `"1", "12", "12-13"` and unvalids `"-2`" and `"12-"`

Comment: Watch out for `\d` as this might not do what you expect! It may stand for any digit character and not just arabic (1, 2, 3, ...). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479423/does-d-in-regex-mean-a-digit

Comment: My house number is 56b. You're not going to get a match for me.

Comment: yes i will, we have a seperate field for that :) you'd have the field house number and additional adress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about following?

```
/^\d+(-\d+)?$/
```

- You don't need to specify `g` flag.
- `?` makes following `-\d+` part optional.

Example:

```
/^\d+(-\d+)?$/.test('1')     //    true
/^\d+(-\d+)?$/.test('12')    //    true
/^\d+(-\d+)?$/.test('12-13') //    true
/^\d+(-\d+)?$/.test('-13')   //    false
/^\d+(-\d+)?$/.test('13-')   //    false
```

Comment: thanks very much. i now the ? operator but didnt quite made it to a working expression. will accept as soon as timer has expired ;)

Comment: Try replacing \d with [0-9]. Will work the exact same except will only match numbers 0 through 9, as \d will match numbers but also other digit characters such as eastern Arabic numerals.

Comment: Won't non-capturing group be of help here? `/^\d+(?:-\d+)?$/`?

Comment: @thefourtheye, It depends on what OP want. If what OP want is just check whether the given string match or not, non-capturing group is redundant in my opinion.

Comment: @falsetru Oh, I thought non-capturing would be efficient in this case.

Comment: non-capturing means i would not have the () available as $1 ?