# Regex not matching when url contains?

Tags: regex

I need a regex match for below set of urls containing ? (question mark)

```
http://mywebsite/page.aspx?MenuId=1
http://mywebsite/page.aspx?MenuId=2
http://mywebsite/page.aspx?MenuId=3
http://mywebsite/page.aspx?MenuId=4
```

pls advise

Comment: This question shows no prior research whatsoever. What have you tried searching for yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via the following regular expression:

```
http\:\/\/mywebsite\/page\.aspx\?MenuId=\d+
```

That will match any url that looks like `http://mywebsite/page.aspx?MenuId=109238091823` with any number entered in the `?MenuId=` parameter being matched.

You can check out http://regex101.com for a good interactive IDE for regular expressions. It also gives you live feedback as you go.

Comment: If your only going to be matching 0-9 its often better to use [0-9]+ not \d+ as \d can also match various other characters

Comment: According to http://regex101.com "\d match a digit [0-9]" so that would make those things exactly the same. What other characters do you say it matches?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479423/does-d-in-regex-mean-a-digit
There will rarely be a case when someone might enter another character that \d matches but just in case using [0-9] is generally better if only matching numbers.