# Ordered os.listdir() in python

Tags: python, file

How to add files into a list by order

In my directory i have the following files: `slide1.xml, slide2.xml, slide3.xml ... slide13.xml`

`os.listdir(path)` doesn't return me a list by order

I've tried this way

```
files_list = [x for x in sorted(os.listdir(path+"/slides/")) if os.path.isfile(path+"/slides/"+x)]
```

output: `['slide1.xml', 'slide10.xml', 'slide11.xml', 'slide12.xml', 'slide13.xml', 'slide2.xml', 'slide3.xml', 'slide3_COPY.xml', 'slide4.xml', 'slide5.xml', 'slide6.xml', 'slide7.xml', 'slide8.xml', 'slide9.xml']`

Comment: I think it is in order, 'slide10.xml' goes before 'slide2.xml'. If you want 'slide2.xml' goes before  'slide10.xml' you need to implement a custom sort

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sort by key:

```
import re
files = ['slide1.xml', 'slide10.xml', 'slide11.xml', 'slide12.xml', 'slide13.xml', 'slide2.xml', 'slide3.xml', 'slide3_COPY.xml', 'slide4.xml', 'slide5.xml', 'slide6.xml', 'slide7.xml', 'slide8.xml', 'slide9.xml']
ordered_files = sorted(files, key=lambda x: (int(re.sub('\D','',x)),x))
```

gives `['slide1.xml', 'slide2.xml', 'slide3.xml', 'slide3_COPY.xml', 'slide4.xml', 'slide5.xml', 'slide6.xml', 'slide7.xml', 'slide8.xml', 'slide9.xml', 'slide10.xml', 'slide11.xml', 'slide12.xml', 'slide13.xml']`

Comment: \d may have problem if your file name contains special character, for example Eastern Arabic numerals ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6479605/2157469

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use your own sort function

```
def custom_sort(x, y):
    pass
    #your custom sort

files_list = [x for x in sorted(os.listdir(path+"/slides/"), cmp=custom_sort) if os.path.isfile(path+"/slides/"+x)]
```

[doc](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#The_Old_Way_Using_the_cmp_Parameter)

also check [natsort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort)