# simplified regex solution for version with format <0-999>.<0-999>.<0-999>

Tags: java, regex, validation

Before everything,

- I have gone through several other regex related questions and also successfully came up with a solution but it looks like there might be a simpler solution
- I am a beginner with regex
- I am using java to execute this server side

Version should be of the format "< major >.< minor >.< beta >" with either of them having a range <0-999>

My desired behaviour is as follows

```
0             -   0.0.0
1             -   1.0.0
000.0.0       -   0.0.0
..9           -   0.0.9
00007         -   7.0.0
090876        -   validate as false
9.00098000.00 -   validate as false
9.0900000.00  -   9.09.0
-13.0.4       -   validate as false
1a.0.4b       -   validate as false
```

My solution is as follows

```
if (StringUtils.isBlank(version)) {
 //set error
} else {
    if (!this.version.trim().matches("\\d+") && !(this.version.trim().matches("^-+"))
 && !(this.version.trim().matches("^+"))) {
        String[] versionsplit = this.version.split("\\.");
        // in the format <major>.<minor>.<beta> for major version, only
        // leading zeroes should be removed
        versionsplit[0] = versionsplit[0].trim().replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");
        if (versionsplit[0].length() == 0) {
            // if major version is left blank add 0
            versionsplit[0] = "0";
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < versionsplit.length; i++) {
            // for minor and beta versions, trailing zeroes should be
            // removed
            versionsplit[i] = versionsplit[i].trim().replaceAll("0*$", "");
            if (versionsplit[i].length() == 0) {
                versionsplit[i] = "0";
            }
        }
        this.version = StringUtils.join(versionsplit, ".");
        if (versionsplit.length < 3) {
            // to comply with the standard format <major>.<minor>.<beta>
            for (int i = versionsplit.length; i < 3; i++) {
                version += ".0";
            }
        }
    } else {
//set error
}

if(< no error check > && !(version.matches("\\d(\\d(\\d)?)?(\\.\\d(\\d(\\d)?)?(\\.\\d(\\d(\\d)?)?)?)?"))) {
// set error    
}
}
```

Tell me if this isn't the most complicated solution, i will be glad to let it be. I just want the code to be readable for the next person.

Please ask if requirement is unclear. Also please don't be frustrated if i do not respond immediately as i am not always online

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I understand the format checker at the end is more accurate in the below way.

```
if(< no error check > && !(version.matches("(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){2}[0-9]{1,3}$"))) {
// set error    
}
```

Comment: Looks like you can use `\\b(?<!\\-)(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){2}[0-9]{1,3}\\b` regex. Or, in case you test isolated strings, `^(?<!\\-)(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){2}[0-9]{1,3}$`

Comment: In general [0-9] is better to use that \d. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479423/does-d-in-regex-mean-a-digit

Comment: Thanks for replying. @Srb1313711  I thought \d is shortform of [0-9]. good to know that some arabic jibberish also passes .

Comment: @stribizhev Now that i think about it, this looks more elegant. Thanks. But is there any way i can also put the _removing leading zeroes in the first group_ and _removing trailing zeroes in the second and third group_ along with what you gave in a single expression. I mean a one or two line code for the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically all you need is a better understanding of regular expressions and how they work in Java.

Here is my code example with the corresponding output, explanations will follow below:

```
    List<String> versions = Arrays.asList("0", "1", "000.0.0", "100.2.3","1.2.3", "..9", "00007", "090876", "9.00098000.00", "9.0900000.00", "-13.0.4", "1a.0.4b", "1.2");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^0*([1-9][0-9]{0,2})?(?:\\.([0-9]{0,3}?)0*(?:\\.([0-9]{0,3}?)0*)?)?$");
    for (String v : versions) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(v);
        Boolean matches = matcher.matches();
        Integer groups = matcher.groupCount();
        System.out.print(v + " evaluates to " + matches);
        // groups is always 3, because the empty string also matches
        if (matches) {
            String major = matcher.group(1);
            if (major == null || major.isEmpty()) {
                major = "0";
            }
            String minor = matcher.group(2);
            if (minor == null || minor.isEmpty()) {
                minor = "0";
            }
            String beta = matcher.group(3);
            if (beta == null || beta.isEmpty()) {
                beta = "0";
            }
            System.out.println(" ---> " + major + "." + minor + "." + beta);
        } else {
            System.out.println();
            // error handling
        }
    }
```

This results in the following output:

```
0 evaluates to true ---> 0.0.0
1 evaluates to true ---> 1.0.0
000.0.0 evaluates to true ---> 0.0.0
100.2.3 evaluates to true ---> 100.2.3
1.2.3 evaluates to true ---> 1.2.3
..9 evaluates to true ---> 0.0.9
00007 evaluates to true ---> 7.0.0
090876 evaluates to false
9.00098000.00 evaluates to false
9.0900000.00 evaluates to true ---> 9.09.0
-13.0.4 evaluates to false
1a.0.4b evaluates to false
1.2 evaluates to true ---> 1.2.0
```

Everything revolves around the pattern and the regular expression it is compiled from. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html?is-external=true is a wonderful resource to get you started (and way beyond started) with regular expressions in Java.

You should look into `capturing` and `not capturing groups` and `quantifiers`, both `greedy` and `reluctant`.

In the regex I've provided above `([1-9][0-9]{0,2})?` is a capturing group for the major version. It must start with a numeric other than 0 and can have up to 2 following numeric characters (this time with 0 included). All the leading nulls are discarded because of the leading `0*` in the regex - observe how it is not inside any capturing group. The greedy quantifier `?` at the end means that this group is optional. The next group is also optional, and it is furthermore a non capturing group, i.e. it won't be accessible after the match is complete. Inside it I discard some zeros and capture two more groups, of which in turn one is optional, using the very same principles.

EDIT: modified answer to accept version strings like x.y as the author suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer is very informative and easy to understand and almost correct. Your code fails for '1.1' input. I modified the pattern that you used into this **^0*([1-9][0-9]{0,2})?(?:\\.([0-9]{0,3}?)0*(?:\\.([0-9]{0,3}?)0*)?)?$** and got correct result. Once check and modify your answer.

Comment: I also wanted it in as few lines as possible and so i have used     " major = (major == null || major.isEmpty()) ? "0" : major; "instead of the if block.

Comment: OK, I didn't think x.y should be accepted as true. But as you have already observed - once you've got the basics you can easily modify the regex to your liking :) I've used if-s for better readability, but you can of course use the ternary operator as long as you're familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is better ), but here is what I have:

```
public static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\d]*)[\\.]?([\\d]*)[\\.]?([\\d]*)");
public static boolean check(String input) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if(!matcher.matches()){
        // NOT MATCH
        return false;
    }

    String major = handleMajor(matcher.group(1));
    String minor = handleMinor(matcher.group(2));
    String rev   = handleMinor(matcher.group(3));
    if (major.length() > 3 || minor.length() > 3 || rev.length() > 3 ){
        // NOT MATCH: over the range 0-999
        return false;
    }

    // MATCH !!!
    System.out.println(major + "." + minor + "." + rev);
    return true;
}

private static String handleMajor(String in){
    if (in.matches("(0*)")) { // replace "" or "00000" with "0"
        return "0";
    } else {                  // remove leading zeros
        return in.replaceFirst("(0+)", "");
    }
}

private static String handleMinor(String in){
    if (in.matches("(0*)")) { // replace "" or "00000" with "000"
        return "000";
    } else {                  // remove trailing zeros
        String res = in + "00";
        while(res.endsWith("0") && res.length() > 3) {
            res = res.substring(0, res.length() - 1);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This definitely looks more readable. But your _handleZeros_ function removes leading  zeroes which is only needed for major version. For minor and beta versions , trailing zeroes should be removed.

Comment: Then 1.10.20 -> 1.1.2?

Comment: i consider a 3 digit format for minor and beta versions. So 1.10.20 = 1.100.200=1.1.2   and 0001.010.2 = 1.010.200=1.01.2

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i guess just neglecting the zeroes in the pattern itself gives better code as @ingenious pointed out