# javascript regular expression for -999x999

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for:

```
-[n digits]x[n digits]
```

I already tried this:

```
var s = "path/path/name-799x1024.jpg"; 
s.replace(/\d/g, "");
```

But this gets only the digits.
Here is a small jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aq6dp49n/

The outcome I try to get is:

```
pfad/pfade/name.jpg
```

How do I add the - and the small x between the two digits?

Comment: Your current expression doesn't seem to match any digits. Are you sure you've shown us the right one?

Comment: `-\d+x\d+` should do, see https://regex101.com/r/dW1wX2/1

Comment: are you trying to store the number of just remove them from `s`?

Answer (score 5):

The regular expression that would match that is `/-\d+x\d+/`. Hence:

```
s.replace(/-\d+x\d+/, "")
```

Should work.

Here's what the regex means: the first `-` tells it that it should look for a `-` character. Then you have `\d+` which means "one or more of `\d`", where `\d` is short-hand for the character class `[0-9]`, i.e., all digits. After that you have `x`, which means it will look for the character `x`, and finally you have `\d+` again, which is the same as before.

Comment: One fateful day many years ago I decided to learn perl, which led me to learning regex. :) I've also added an explanation about the meaning of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

To match

```
-[n digits]x[n digits]
```

You would want

```
match(/-[0-9]{n}x[0-9]{n}\b/)
```

Though if you want an arbitrary (one or more) number of digits, use `+` in place of `{n}`.  In the case of your example, you'd want 3 and 4 for your values of `n`.

Here's a [step-by-step explanation of what this does](https://regex101.com/r/bX8fS1/1):

```
/-[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{4}\b/

    - matches the character - literally
    [0-9]{3} match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: {3} Exactly 3 times
        0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
    x matches the character x literally (case sensitive)
    [0-9]{4} match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: {4} Exactly 4 times
        0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
    \b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
```

To remove the *last* size-like part of a string, this should do:

```
"path/path/name-799x1024.jpg".replace(/(.*)-[0-9]+x[0-9]+/, "$1");
// "path/path/name.jpg"
"path/path/name-10x12-799x1024.jpg".replace(/(.*)-[0-9]+x[0-9]+/, "$1");
// "path/path/name-10x12.jpg"
```

This takes advantage of the fact that regexps are greedy, so the `(.*)` absorbs (and saves) as much preceding text as possible before finding the next match.

(I prefer to use `[0-9]` in place of `\d` because it's more specific ([`\d` also matches non-latin numerals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479423/does-d-in-regex-mean-a-digit/6479605#6479605)) and therefore slightly faster, though in this case it shouldn't matter.)