# Regular expression for matching hw:n,n

Tags: regex, string

Can someone help me with a regular expression for matching hw:n,n?

where n is any number between 0-9.

an example string would be hw:0,1

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is very simple, just use the digit identifier `\d`:

```
hw:\d,\d
```

https://regex101.com/r/oU1bI7/1

The above regex might also match other numerals, such as the arabic ones (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6479605/1105858)

If you want to limit to the actual 10 digits `0–9`, you can use it as a character class:

```
hw:[0-9],[0-9]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
hw:[0-9]+,[0-9]+
```

`[0-9]+`: matches one or more digits

`,`: matches a comma