# Regular expression doesn't extract whole the id from a log file?

Tags: python, regex

I have following input in the log file which I am interested to capture all the part of IDs, however it won't return me the whole of the ID and just returns me some part of that:

```
id:A2uhasan30hamwix١٦٠٢٢٧١٣٣٣١١٣٥٤ 
id:A2uhasan30hamwix160212145302428 
id:A2uhasan30hamwix١٦٠٢٠٩١٣٠١٥٠٠١١ 
id:A2uhasan30hamwix١٦٠٢٠٩١٦٤٧٣٩٧٣٢ 
id:A2uhasan30hamwix١٦٠٢٠٨١٩٢٨٠١٩٠٧ 
id:A2uhasan30hamwix160207145023750
```

I have used the following regular expression with python 2.7:

```
I have edited sid to id:
RE_SID = re.compile(r'sid:(<<")?(?P<sid>([A-Za-z0-9._+]*))', re.U)
```

to

```
>>> RE_SID = re.compile(ur'id:(<<")?(?P<sid>[A-Za-z\d._+]*)', re.U)
>>> sid = RE_SID.search('id:A2uhasan30hamwix١٦٠٢٢٧١٣٣٣١١٣٥٤').group('sid')
>>> sid
'A2uhasan30hamwix'
```

and this is my result:

```
is: A2uhasan30hamwix
```

After edit:
This is how I am reading the log file:

```
with open(cfg.log_file) as input_file: ...
     fields = line.strip().split(' ')
```

and an example of line in log:

```
2015-11-30T23:58:13.760950+00:00 calxxx enexxxxce[10476]: INFO consume_essor: user:<<"ailxxxied">> callee_num:<<"+144442567413">> id:<<"A2uhasan30hamwix١٦٠٢٠٨١٩٢٨٠١٩٠٧">> credits:0.0 result:ok provider:sipovvvv1.yv.vs
```

I will appreciated to help me to edit my regular expression.

Comment: Do you want your regex to also capture the arabic numerals?

Comment: Try [`id:(<<")?(?P<sid>[A-Za-z\d._+]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/wW6mE2/1). Note you do not have `sid:` in your input.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have changed to `RE_SID = re.compile(r'id:(<<")?(?P<sid>[A-Za-z\d._+]*)', re.U)`. Output of my python is still the same without any changes.

Comment: What version of Python is it? How do you obtain the input string? Please post all relevant details in the quesiton. You also need to use `u` alongside the `r` prefix.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew It is exactly as I have shown in above. just the latin alphabet. python version is : 2.7 . I have added ur as prefix , not changing! I would update some thing more!

Comment: *I have following input in the log file* - did you encode it in UTF8 after `read()`ing it?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew no, I didn't encode it, how?

Comment: Please post the code showing how you read the file in. It should be something like `import codecs //
f = codecs.open('myFile.txt', encoding='utf-8') //
for line in f:`, or after reading it, use `.encode('utf-8')` on it.

Comment: I edited your question with my suggestion, please check. I get `A2uhasan30hamwix١٦٠٢٢٧١٣٣٣١١٣٥٤`, `A2uhasan30hamwix160212145302428`, `A2uhasan30hamwix١٦٠٢٠٩١٣٠١٥٠٠١١`, `A2uhasan30hamwix١٦٠٢٠٩١٦٤٧٣٩٧٣٢`, `A2uhasan30hamwix١٦٠٢٠٨١٩٢٨٠١٩٠٧`, `A2uhasan30hamwix160207145023750`

Comment: Is that code working for you?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, I have user `with open` and there is not any encoding parameter for that. As I am new to the python, I would like to be sure that this change doesn't have a side affect in whole the code, I mean I have write too `csvwriter = csv.writer(csv_test,quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)`. Do I have to change the rest of things as well?

Comment: Writing is something different, please do not make the question *too broad*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107724/discussion-between-maryam-pashmi-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what we discussed in the chat, posting the solution:

```
import codecs
import re
RE_SID = re.compile(ur'id:(<<")?(?P<sid>[A-Za-z\d._+]*)', re.U) # \d used to match non-ASCII digits, too
input_file = codecs.open(cfg.log_file, encoding='utf-8')  # Read the file with UTF8 encoding
for line in input_file: 
    fields = line.strip().split(u' ') # u prefix is important!
    if len(fields) >= 11: 
    try: 
        # ...... 
        sid = RE_SID.search(fields[7]).group('sid') # Or check if there is a match first
```

Comment: I would like to add, I could use `with codecs.open(cfg.log_file, encoding='utf-8') as input_file:` using `codecs.open` with `with` and it works perfectly too. The interesting point is that in this case I don't need to write even `u` in `....split(u' ')` and will work with `fields = line.strip().split(' ')` @Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 1):

3 things to fix:

- `id` instead of `sid`
- use `\d` instead of `0-9` to [also catch the arabic numerals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6479605/771848)
- no need to add an extra capturing group inside the `sid` named group

Fixed version:

```
id:(<<")?(?P<sid>[A-Za-z\d_.+]+)
```

Comment: I have change to what you written there, the result are the same without the arabic numbers `RE_SID = re.compile(r'id:(<<")?(?P<sid>[A-Za-z\d_.+]+)', re.U)`

Answer (score 0):

```
string = '''
id:A2uhasan30hamwix١٦٠٢٢٧١٣٣٣١١٣٥٤ 
id:A2uhasan30hamwix160212145302428 
id:A2uhasan30hamwix١٦٠٢٠٩١٣٠١٥٠٠١١ 
id:A2uhasan30hamwix١٦٠٢٠٩١٦٤٧٣٩٧٣٢ 
id:A2uhasan30hamwix١٦٠٢٠٨١٩٢٨٠١٩٠٧ 
id:A2uhasan30hamwix160207145023750
'''
import re
reObj = re.compile(r'id:.*')
ans = reObj.findall(string,re.DOTALL)

print(ans)
```

**Output :**

```
['id:A2uhasan30hamwix160212145302428 ', 
 'id:A2uhasan30hamwix١٦٠٢٠٩١٣٠١٥٠٠١١ ', 
 'id:A2uhasan30hamwix١٦٠٢٠٩١٦٤٧٣٩٧٣٢ ', 
 'id:A2uhasan30hamwix١٦٠٢٠٨١٩٢٨٠١٩٠٧ ', 
 'id:A2uhasan30hamwix160207145023750']
```