# Regex - must contain number and must not contain special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check by regex if:

1. String contains number
2. String does not contain special characters (!<>?=+@{}_$%)

Now it looks like:
`^[^!<>?=+@{}_$%]+$`

How should I edit this regex to check if there is number anywhere in the string (it must contain it)?

Comment: What is everything that the regex should allow? This is how I would go about it to make it much simpler.

Comment: Using an online regex checker might help. See this tool https://regex101.com/

Comment: Regex should allow all the strings that does not contain special characters AND contain at least one number. It will be used to check if there is a number in address field.

Answer (score 3):

you can add `[0-9]+` or `\d+` into your regex, like this:

`^[^!<>?=+@{}_$%]*[0-9]+[^!<>?=+@{}_$%]*$`
or
`^[^!<>?=+@{}_$%]*\d+[^!<>?=+@{}_$%]*$`

different between `[0-9]` and `\d` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479423/does-d-in-regex-mean-a-digit)

Comment: It's quite unsatisfying to have the same character class repeated twice in the same regexp. By the way, the link you posted is for Python. In JS, `\d` is **exactly** equivalent to `[0-9]`.

Comment: @torazaburo Perhaps in JS this is the case, but I seem to recall that `\d` can include unicode characters in some other flavor of regex.

Comment: Sure, but this question is about JS.

Answer (score 2):

Just look ahead for the digit:

```js
var re = /^(?=.*\d)[^!<>?=+@{}_$%]+$/;

console.log(re.test('bob'));
console.log(re.test('bob1'));
console.log(re.test('bob#'))
```

The `(?=.*\d)` part is the lookahead for a single digit somewhere in the input.

Comment: How did I not see this answer before I posted? Gargh!! ;P

Answer (score 0):

You only needed to add the number check, is that right? You can do it like so:

`/^(?=.*\d)[^!<>?=+@{}_$%]+$/`

We do a lookahead (like peeking at the following characters without moving where we are in the string) to check to see if there is at least one number anywhere in the string. *Then* we do our normal check to see if none of the characters are those symbols, moving through the string as we go.

Just as a note: If you want to match newlines (a.k.a. line breaks), then you can change the dot `.` into `[\W\w]`. This matches any character whatsoever. You can do this in a number of ways, but they're all pretty much as clunky as each other, so it's up to you.

Comment: Isn't it the same like torazaburo's solutions above?

Comment: Yeah--saw that just as I posted. But mine gives a little context and whatever, so it wasn't completely wasted ;D