# Regular Expression for minimum value 18 and maximum 99 with leading zero

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

Regular Expression for minimum value 18 and maximum 99 with leading zero.
Means my number should be from  18 to  99. With one condition of leading zero i.e 18 == 018, 99 == 099

Comment: what is your expectation from stackoverflow?

Comment: if (v> 17 && v < 100) ?

Comment: I need regular expression for the  above question.

Comment: If your allowable values are 18-99, how does a leading zero fit in to this?

Comment: @Mykola Borysyuk   I want this (v> 17 && v < 100)  condition in regex.

Comment: I'd change the value in **column 2 to 8** of your code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this it will help you

Less than 18 and greater than 99 is not allowed

```
^(1[89]|[2-9][0-9])$
```

Comment: This does not address the criteria regarding leading zero

Comment: Am trying to enter value only between 0 to 1000 (including 0 and 1000). but its not working. Am using this regex  `/^0?1[01]|0?[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/ `

Answer (score 4):

`^0?1[89]|0?[2-9][0-9]$`

- ^ - beginning of string
- 0? - allow beginning 0
- 1[89] - match first character 1 and second 8 or 9
- | - or
- 0? - allow beginning 0
- [2-9] - match first character 2-9
- [0-9] - match second character 0-9
- $ - end of string

Comment: that won't allow 099 (and surely \d )

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
^0?(1[89]|[2-9]\d)$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/CrcbHN/1

Comment: well, `0?(1[89]|[2-9]\d)` is just as good :p (you'll also need ^ and $ to truly "validate"

Comment: Sure, but https://regex101.com/r/ht2mil/3 works just as well, with four less characters (i.e. the extra () ())

Comment: I am glad that worked :) I have recently started learning about regex.

Answer (score 0):

`(01[89])|(0[2-9]\d)`

- `(01[89])` matches 018 to 019
- `(0[2-9]\d)` matches 020 to 099

Comment: no, that requires a leading 0, not optional as stated in the request for code - I mean, question

Comment: But leading zero _is_ required in question, isn't it?

Comment: I took `With one condition of leading zero` to mean, in English `with one optional leading zero` - but you're probably right :p

Answer (score 0):

Try with below,

```
0([1][89]|[2-9][0-9])
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/vc8ex5/3)

Comment: `[0-9]+` a) what's wrong with \d - and b) that would allow, say 029631027910246741584

Comment: @JaromandaX You are right on b) part I am working on it for \d see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479423/does-d-in-regex-mean-a-digit

Comment: ahh, I see the issue with \d (though, not sure how JS handles \d but you have an excellent point about it)