# Regular Expression for a string starts with four capital alhpa and followed by numeric. total length should be minimum 15

Tags: regex

Guys Please help me in creating a regular expression for  a string starts with four capital alpha and followed by numeric. total length should be minimum 15 and max 30

e.g.

```
ABCD12322323231 , ABCD12322323231343 is a valid
123ABC, ABC12321, ABCD12, ABCD-12323123123123213213213 are invalid
```

I were trying with

```
(^([A-Z]){4}){15,30}$)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this and where are you stuck?

Comment: Added the regular expression which i am trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this I believe:

```
[A-Z]{4}\d{11,26}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{11,26}
```

Explanation:

```
[A-Z] => Anything between A to Z
{4}   => Repeat 4 times
[0-9] => Anything between 0 to 9
{11,26} => Repeat 11 to 26 times
```

The numeric part length is limited to between 11 to 26 so that the total length is between 15 to 30.

[0-9] is preferred to \d because the latter matches all Unicode digits rather than just 0-9.

Comment: What's the difference between unicode digits and normal digits?

Comment: [0-9] matches only 0123456789 characters, while \d matches [0-9] and other digit characters, for example Eastern Arabic numerals ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6479605/7362939