# sed not capturing \w even with extended regexp

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, sh

So, I have this string `90d_ASD_A98CAWd9A_WF8`, and I want to capture the `\w` group of characters in it and remove them. `\w` captures both uppercase and lowercase alphabetical characters and the underscore.

However, even though sed identifies the `\w` group, it doesn't replace the `\w` group characters in the string, even if I enable extended regexp using the `-E` option.

If I execute this:

```bash
echo "90d_ASD_A98CAWd9A_WF8" | sed -E s/"[\w]+"//g
```

I get:

```
90d_ASD_A98CAWd9A_WF8
```

However, if I explicitly mention the range of the characters I want to remove in the regexp:

```bash
echo "90d_ASD_A98CAWd9A_WF8" | sed -E s/"[A-Za-z_]+"//g
```

I get exactly what I'm expecting: the string with all the uppercase and lowercase alphabets and underscores removed:

```
909898
```

Am I using the `\w` group wrongly? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all `\w` equivalent to `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` not `[A-Za-z_]`. So if you need to remove only letters and underscore, use your second command.

Comment: Also for compatibility reasons it is better to use `[[:alnum:]_]` instead of `\w` as support for meta sequences is limited.

Comment: If you want to extract decimal digits only, use `sed 's/[^0-9]//g'`. Also note that not all `sed`s support `\w`.

Comment: @markalex understood. But in that case I should be getting an empty string in the first example, right? As all of the characters in the string `90d_ASD_A98CAWd9A_WF8` match the regex `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`. Why didn't that happen?

Comment: Regarding your exact problem `sed` threats `[\w]` as any of ``\`` or `w`. I don't know why. But if your version of `sed` supports `\w` you can simply write `'s/\w+//g'`

Comment: Inside `[]` `\w` is just a simple `w`. Plus, `\w` matches also digits. Try `echo "90d_ASD_A98CAWd9A_WF8" | sed -E 's/[^0-9]//g'` (also note the single quotes around the `sed` script and no double quotes in it).

Comment: What ever is inside the `[....]` is called [bracket expression](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05)

Comment: @markalex or `[[:alpha:]_]` or `[^[:digit:]]`...

Comment: Actually, `[\w]` in a POSIX regex [matches both ``\`` and `w`](https://ideone.com/7WBxQ7). The [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46021796/3832970) is simple, Perl-like shorthand character classes are not treated as such inside POSIX bracket expressions.