# Metacharacters vs Character ranges in Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, class, range, character

I see more often that people use:
[0-9] instead of \d and [A-Za-z0-9_] instead of \w

Is there some inconsistencies between browsers or other drawbacks when using metacharacters?
Should i use character ranges instead of corresponding metacharacters?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9

Answer (score 1):

No known inconsistencies, but two possible reasons.

First, both `\d` and `\w` mean different things in different RegExp implementations. Quoting [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html):

> Since certain character classes are used often, a series of shorthand
>   character classes are available. `\d` is short for `[0-9]`. In most
>   flavors that support Unicode, `\d` includes all digits from all scripts.
>   **Notable exceptions are Java, JavaScript, and PCRE.** These Unicode
>   flavors match only ASCII digits with `\d`.

So, yes, JavaScript is safe in this regard - but if you mostly deal with other implementations (like [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/1229023) and [Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6479605/1229023)), you might just not be aware of this.

Second, some developers might prefer `[0-9]` to `\d` just because, well, [explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python).