# Match everything that's not a digit or white space at the end of a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a field that looks like this :

```
------->Total cash dispensed: 40000 MGA
```

I want to get only the "MGA" using regex but without using split

```
regex = r"Total cash dispensed:\s*([^ 0-9]*)"
```

The code I used to get anything that's not number or white space does not work, How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you please include some examples with the expected results in those cases?

Comment: `\d+\s*([A-Z]+)$` ?

Comment: So you want the last part of a string after the last space? Why use regex? Why not `s.rsplit(' ', 1)[-1]`?

Comment: To answer your question in the title most simply: `[^ \d]+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a capture group:

```
\bTotal cash dispensed:\s*\d+\s+([A-Z]+)\b
```

- `\bTotal cash dispensed:\s*` Match the text starting with a word boundary and followed by `:` and optional whitespace chars
- `\d+\s+` Match 1+ digits and 1+ whitespace chars
- `([A-Z]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ chars A-Z
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jgPfWg/1)

```
import re
 
pattern = r"\bTotal cash dispensed:\s*\d+\s+([A-Z]+)\b"
s = "------>Total cash dispensed: 40000 MGA"
 
matches = re.search(pattern, s)
 
if matches:
    print(matches.group(1))
```

Output

```
MGA
```

Comment: Just to clarify: `\d` is not the same as `[0-9]` :) Example: `re.match('\d', '١')`

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Right, [`(?a)\d` = `[0-9]`](https://ideone.com/Cvavwr) in Python 3. `\d` matches any Unicode digits by default. `re.ASCII` / `re.A` or `(?a)` can be used to make `\d` equal to `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can match anything except whitespace and digits with the following expression:

```
[^\s\d]+
```

"`\s\`" is whitespace, including spaces, tabs, and enters

"`\d`" is digits, same as `[0-9]` and some other numeric characters from other scripts

Example:

```
re.search('[^\s\d]+', '123 \t')
# -> No match
```

Comment: `\d` is not the same as `[0-9]`

Comment: Based on this source Riccardo is right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479423/does-d-in-regex-mean-a-digit#6479605

Comment: `re.match('\d', '١')`