# Remove a sub-string in a string to rewrite a robust xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath

I need to remove the `value` attribute from this xpath. (In this example there are two `value` attributes).

I create the xpath in a string:

```
"xpath": "//iframe[@title=\"s='replaceable-modal-title'>Compléter mes entretiens</span><input type='hidden' id='assessDurationIdverif' value='2091' /><input type='hidden' id='employeeIdverif' value='1368' />\"]/html/body/div[2]/section/div/div[4]/div/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/textarea"
```

My first idea was to use the [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to replace attribute's value with an empty string:

```
string.replace(/value=(2091)/g,'test')
```

My problem is that the `value` attribute does not have the same value when I refresh the page.

I just want to know how to generically replace the number by undefined character.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with `String#replace` and a regular expression.

To handle the `value` attribute changing when the page reloads, use the [`\d` digit character class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479423/does-d-in-regex-mean-a-digit) which represents any character in `0-9`. Using `\d*` matches zero or more digits and `\d+` matches one or more digits.

Here's an example that matches all `value` attributes with digits in their values and replaces the whole attribute with an empty string:

```js
const foo = "//iframe[@title=\"s='replaceable-modal-title'>Compléter mes entretiens</span><input type='hidden' id='assessDurationIdverif' value='2091' /><input type='hidden' id='employeeIdverif' value='1368' />\"]/html/body/div[2]/section/div/div[4]/div/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/textarea";

const bar = foo.replace(/value='\d+'/g, '');

console.log(foo);
console.log(bar);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. it was a great help for me!