# Regular expresion for 000 to 999

Tags: regex

I try to create a regular expression that allow me to filter values that start with these ranges: 000 to 999

I try with this ^[001-999]{3}$ but it doesn't work well with ranges to 000 to 099

Thanks for your help

Comment: What happens with this a bit too loose? `^[0-9]{3}$` should be simpler.

Comment: you just need all cases where there are 3 digits? `^\d{3}$`

Comment: Regex only knows about characters, not about numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
^\d{1,3}$
```

Here's a [visualization](https://regexper.com/#%5E%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%24) to explain what this pattern is doing.

If you only want exactly three digits, use `{3}` instead of `{1,3}` (which will also allow 1 or 2 digits): [`^\d{3}$`](https://regexper.com/#%5E%5Cd%7B3%7D%24)

If your regex engine does not support `\d`, use `[0-9]` instead: [`^[0-9]{3}$`](https://regexper.com/#%5E%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%24)

Comment: @user3783243. Which feature specifically?

Comment: @MadPhysicist `\d` (questions been updated for work around)

Comment: Worth reading this answer for a much more comprehensive discussion of `\d` vs. `[0-9]`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479423/does-d-in-regex-mean-a-digit