# Match password with Python regex

Tags: python, regex

The requirements for my password are:

- at least 10 symbols
- at least one digit
- at least one uppercase letter
- at least one lowercase letter
- only letters or digits

So I want to use the re module to check my string input: `re.search(pattern, string)`.

What should be my pattern here?

Comment: Im not sure regex is the right tool for this

Comment: What do you mean by 10 symbols? you mean the length must be atleast 10?

Comment: `len(x) >= 10` Im sure ... what else do you expect? are you thinking `len(set(x))`?

Comment: @JoranBeasley yep, it's possible through regex.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, I mean at least 10 chars

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep, you could do this through regex.

```
^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])[A-Za-z\d]{10,}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aQ9vG2/1)

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.compile(r'^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])[A-Za-z\d]{10,}$')
>>> m.match('43543fooR')
>>> m.match('43543fooRy')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='43543fooRy'>
>>> m.match('foobar7678A')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 11), match='foobar7678A'>
>>> m.match('foobar76(')
>>> m.match('fokhjf7645464644sresrtf')
>>> m.match('fokhjf764546M4644sresrtf')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 24), match='fokhjf764546M4644sresrtf'>
>>>
```

- `(?=.*?\d)` Checks for atleast one digit
- `(?=.*?[A-Z])` Atleast one uppercsae.
- `(?=.*?[a-z])` Atleast one lowercase.
- `[A-Za-z\d]{10,}` Matches uppercase or lowercase or digit characters 10 or more times. This ensures that the match must have atleast 10 characters.

Comment: dang nice work ... you are a regex boss ... that hurt my head to much to try and come up with a regex solution

Comment: One quick question, for the last condition, can I use \W+{10, }?

Comment: not `\W`, it's `\w`. But `\w` would match `_` (underscore) also.

Comment: thanks, just one more thing, I do not understand when to use (), like in your example, three are in (), and 10 characters with no (). I still am puzzled on this.

Comment: `(?=...)` called positive lookahead assertion. This won't capture any characters put asserts whether the match would happen or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
while True:
    passw = input("password: ")
    if len(passw)<10:
        print ("not enough")
        continue
    if passw.isalpha():
        print ("atleast 1 digit")
        continue
    if passw.islower():
        print ("at least 1 uppercase")
        continue
    if pass.isupper():
        print ("Do you even password?")
        continue
    else:
        print ("Finally, you created a password that FBI using.")
```

Output;

```
>>> 
password: a
not enough
password: asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadsads
atleast 1 digit
password: asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdads1111
at least 1 uppercase
password: asASasdasdasdasdasdas111
Finally, you created a password that FBI using.
password:
```

Use `if` statements, check the lenght first. Then check is there any digit with `isalpha()`. Then check is there any uppercase with `islower()`. You don't need `regex`.

Comment: why the downvote? (you might want to check `isupper` also ... but no reason for -1 that I can see)

Comment: @downvoter, could you put a reason then I can improve my answer?

Comment: ASD44DSAASD22 would pass even though it does not have the required at least 1 lower (anyway I upvoted to offset the mystery downvoter)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Ohhhh sorry you are right. I miss that condiiton. You know this password for FBI :-) Thank's for warning I'm going to add that

Answer (score -4):

Here is a similar article that answers most of your question [How to test a regex password in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990654/how-to-test-a-regex-password-in-python)

You might also find the regular expression cookbook helpful https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s19.html

Live Demo: https://ideone.com/4PGlTu

```
import re

password = raw_input("Enter string to test: ")

atLeastTenCharacters = ".{10,}"
hasAtLeastTenCharacters = re.findall(atLeastTenCharacters, password)
if (not hasAtLeastTenCharacters):
    print "Password should be at least 10 characters long!"

atLeastOneDigit = "[0-9]"
hasAtLeastOneDigit = re.findall(atLeastOneDigit, password)
if (not hasAtLeastOneDigit):
    print "Password should have at least one digit!"

atLeastOneUpper = "[A-Z]"
hasAtLeastOneUpper = re.findall(atLeastOneUpper, password)
if (not hasAtLeastOneUpper):
    print "Password should have at least one upper case character!"

atLeastOneLower = "[a-z]"
hasAtLeastOneLower = re.findall(atLeastOneLower, password)
if (not hasAtLeastOneLower):
    print "Password should have at least one lower case character!"

specialCharacters = "[^A-Za-z0-9]"
hasSpecialCharacters = re.findall(specialCharacters, password)
if (hasSpecialCharacters):
    print "Password should NOT have special characters!"

if (hasAtLeastTenCharacters and hasAtLeastOneDigit and hasAtLeastOneUpper and hasAtLeastOneLower and (not hasSpecialCharacters)):
    print "\nValid password"
else:
    print "\nPassword not valid"
```

Comment: this is not an answer and really doesnt adress OP's question ... granted it is somewhat simillar