# Python Regex - STRING with [A-Z] and DIGITS [\d]

Tags: python, regex

```
import re 

 str_1 = "ABABABABABAabababaacdcdcdcd"
 str_2 = "ABABABABAB1ab2babaacdcdcdcd"
 str_3 = "123456A"
 str_4 = "123456"

 #str_3Plus_d = re.search(r'(?=.*?\d)[A-Z\d]{10,}',str_2).group(0)
 str_3Plus_d = re.search(r'(?=.*?\d)[A-Z\d]{2,4}',str_2).group(0)
 print(str_3Plus_d)

 #str_3plus_a = re.search(r'(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[A-Z])[A-Z\d]{3,}',str_4).group(0)

 #str_3plus_both = re.search(r'(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[A-Z])[A-Z\d]{3,}',str_4).group(0)
```

I am stuck with searching a STRING ([A-Z] and DIGITS). I searched SO for similar Questions ,  here -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28334645/4928635, it says that **(?=.*?\d)** "Checks for atleast one digit" , but that doesnt seem to be the case. As seen in -

```
str_3Plus_d = re.search(r'(?=.*?\d)[A-Z\d]{2,4}',str_2).group(0)
print(str_3Plus_d)
```

it prints me a string - which has no digits ? String it print in my JupyterNotebook is as seen below -

```
 ABAB
```

How to capture a string with - "variable number of characters and at least 2 digits and at most 4 digits , as an example - how to catch - AAABBB2223" ...

Further clarifications --

1. @pm-2ring :- the digits and alpha characters can occur in any order , the substring im trying to capture can vary in length.
2. @jean-françois-fabre :- you seem to have removed your answer - the code you gave did exactly what u said it would - thanks .
3. @clasg :- Both your comment and answer have taught me well today - im very grateful - i will revert in sometime and let you know if i would want to upvote your answer - many thanks.

Comment: what about `"([A-Z]+\d\d+)"` simply? why the non-capturing stuff ?

Comment: Your regex matches 2-4 letters or digits. The look ahead `(?=.*?\d)` has no limitation in characters. So if the digit comes in position 5 or later, the look ahead finds it, but it doesn't get matched by `[A-Z\d]{2,4}`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's not a *non capturing* group. It's a *positive look-ahed*.

Comment: @ClasG yeah maybe, but too complex for this issue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre On the contrary, it is much more readable compared to enumerating all possibilities inside an alternation group. However, the lookahead pattern does not look appropriate. I doubt I understand what OP wants, so I vote to close as unclear.

Comment: Also, will the digits always be at the end of the string, or can the digits and alpha characters occur in any order? Do you want the matching strings to always have at least one alpha character?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by moving the quantification into the look-ahead and some...

```
^(?=(?:[^\d\n]*\d){2,4}[^\d\n]*$)[A-Z\d]*$
```

It's a bit more complex, but does the work, as it should.

The `[^\d\n]` matches anything but digits or newlines. Making the positive look-ahead match this construct any number of times (`*`), followed by a digit, then repeating *this* 2-4 times, finally followed by the *non digit/LF again*, makes it only match a string if it contains between 2 and 4 digits.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Q9WunC/3).