# How to require a capital letter and a number for an input string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords

```py
password = input(str("Please enter a password with a capital letter and a number: "))
for char in password:
    if password.islower() and "1234567890" not in password:
        print("Your password will need to have at least one number and at least one capitalized letter")
        password = input("Please enter another password: ")
```

**The error phrase will print if a password is entered without a number or capital, but if a capital is used in the input the error string doesn't run even though the input is still missing a number. Same for if the input has a number but not a capital letter. I want both a capital letter and a number to be required for the input as you can probably tell. Thanks.

edit:
I don't want to know how to make a password requirement program. I specifically want to know why the "and not" is not working.**

Comment: Please use search before posting a new question. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990654/how-to-test-a-regex-password-in-python which is close to your scenario.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/2990654/… isn't what I'm looking for. The solutions in the comments of that post don't work for what I am wanting to know. Thanks.@Sathish Guru

Comment: You haven't actually implemented the logic your text describes. You want to reject a password that is lowercase **or** alphabetic, not only those that are lowercase *and* alphabetic. You want to reject a password that doesn't have *any* number in it, not one that doesn't have the consecutive numbers from 1-9 and 0 in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just happened to write this yesterday.
Season to taste :-)

```
import re
import getpass
while True:
    pwd = getpass.getpass('please enter a password: ')
    if len(pwd) >= 8 and re.search('[0-9]', pwd) and re.search('[A-Z]', pwd):
        if pwd != getpass.getpass('please reenter password: '):
            print('passwords do not match')
        else:
            break
    else:
        print('passwords must contain 8 characters and at least one uppercase letter and one digit')

print('approved pwd:', pwd)
```

Answer (score 0):

*I specifically want to know why the "and not" is not working*.

```
"1234567890" not in password
```

is negation of `"1234567890" in password` which for `password` being `str` is checking if `"1234567890"` is *substring* of `password`.
Consider that:

```
print("123" in "123123123")  # True
print("123" in "1")  # False
print("123" in "321")  # False
```

To check if any character from one `str` is present in second `str` you might check if intersection is not empty - just turn second `str` into `set`, get interesection with first, and use `bool` function on result, thus getting `True` if at least one of characters of first str is present in second and `False` otherwise:

```
x = "1234567890"
y = "sometextandnumber0"
print(bool(set(y).intersection(x)))  # True
```

Comment: Note that ``str.isdigit`` is simpler than creating sets of strings and their intersections.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: `str.isdigit` check if *all* characters are digits, so for `abc123` it gives `False`, when intersection solution check if *at least one* character is one from specified.

Comment: You need to apply it per character, of course, i.e. ``any(map(str.isdigit, y))``.